# Screen scraping friend lists in Facebook, for Python

Tags: python, facebook, screen, screen-scraping

I require to obtain a list of FB friends of my friend... actually, of all my friends. The FB API won't let me get a list of friends of anyone who isn't me, but I can get these lists manually in my browser.

I want to get these lists. Somehow. It doesn't have to go straight into Python (I can always just get the data from, say, html versions of the friend lists) but I have no idea how to go about automating the whole "go to friend, open friend list, save page" thing. I I have a feeling I can use browser automation but... Well, I tried using Selenium and I could not crack it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) makes it easier to automate these things in complex situations. It might be overkill in this case though. It would be quite easy using [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) or [lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) to get your friend-list and get their ID's, and from there generate the URLs to their friend-list, and rinse+repeat.

Comment: Now as it happens, I have a list of friend uids, thanks to the API. But how would I go about using these to access the lists?

Comment: You would generate the URL that lists their friends and scrape them with BeautifulSoup or lxml, as explained above.

Comment: Hmm... I believe that requires logging into Facebook using Python, as those pages require being logged in. How would I do this bit using Mechanize?

Comment: I'm not going to actually write your code for you. ;-) You'll have to read the docs, try and ask new questions if you have problems. You can log in with just urllib as well, but you'll have to track the cookies "manually", and it's a bit involved I think. But you can probably find examples on how to do that here on Stackoverflow already.

Comment: Okey dokey :D I'll look further into it~ Thanks :D